# Does the FFT of a price series hold any significance?

Tags: stock-analysis, technical-analysis, volatility

I'm just wondering whether spectral/frequency information (by means of a Fast Fourier Transform) about a stock's price series holds any significance in investment?

My expectation is that it would provide insight into volatility over the window. Has anyone seen other uses for spectral information?

Comment: Past results are no guarantee of future performance. Any periodicity (which is what the FFT would display) could be an artifact of conditions which no longer exist. It might givd you a reason to dig deeper, but I wouldn't bet on it as a direct indicator.